Unreadable options on 23.04 -> 23.10 EOL upgrade (corrupted text)
I am attempting to upgrade an End of Life (EOL) Ubuntu release to a supported system using the Ubuntu advice here. I am moving from Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) to 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur), using the version-specific upgrader from here.
I am now impacted by a text corruption bug: reported here; and mistakenly (though helpfully) recognised as Russian here. Copying the corrupted text, and pasting it, say, to "GNOME Text Editor", or the command-line, decodes it; and so I was able to proceed past a corrupted "Remove obsolete packages?" window (btw. Left button is "Keep"; Right button is "Remove"), but the next message box (shown below) has me stumped; especially as there is no copy-able text. Can anyone tell me what these options are?
The first screengrab below is the foreground window which is asking me to make a choice. The second screengrab is a contextual window in the background. Can anyone help?



Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

If the font issue is during the release-upgrade, that is only temporary and you needn't worry about it. It only occurred if certain apps were left running if I recall correctly. Either way Ubuntu 23.10 is now EOL & thus off-topic here; this site can help you when you try to move from 23.10 to a supported release such as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (noble).

@guiverc Thanks. I agree it should only be a temporary problem, it's just I don't know which of the two buttons to click. Perhaps someone recognises this likely common popup window from the context.

I recall reaching that issue back during QA (2023-September), but I sure don't recall what options were; not enough to advise.  Given the warnings & notices in the release notes; I'd have performed the release-upgrade via text mode to avoid that issue (there was specific mention of it if I recall correctly in some docs too; but that was long ago & I'm not searching for it - it's unsupported; my last comment on that report was Oct 2023).   If you really want to know, setup a VM & perform a ~like release-upgrade and see for yourself what you should see

The foreground window normally looks something like this:

(Which comes from the "Upgrade Ubuntu desktop" article here.)
I got there after noticing that the first two glyphs in the message box looked like the start of the text from the previous "Remove obsolete packages?" window (which is copy-able). I then used Zenity to create windows with garbled titles from clear originals. I started by guessing words that begin with "Re", like "Retry" and "Remove". After getting "Restart" I focused on the left button: "Restart Now". (Invocations such as zenity --info --text="Hello" --width=800 --title="Restart Now Close a b c d e f g h i j k l m o n p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M O N P Q R S T U V W X Y Z" --ok-label="Press Me".) I was then able to use Google and select the Images tab to get the image above.
Clicking the left button concluded the release-upgrade successfully.
